# toLocaleString in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code javascript:

```
valueToBelocl = 9876543210123456;
modLocale = "en-US";
valueToBelocl = valueToBelocl.toLocaleString(modLocale);
```

ressult: 9,876,543,210,123,460

Expected:9,876,543,210,123,456

Please help me make correct result!
Thanks!

Comment: `to LocaleString` is formatting... what sort of formatting involves 4 digits less than the original value? Precision Ok I see.

Comment: Thanks! @ADreNaLiNe-DJ , it's save my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer you are using is too long for your JavaScript implementation. You should not use integers larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is `9,007,199,254,740,991` on most engines today.

If you want to work with large integers, you should use [specific](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint). This won't really help you with formatting it out-of-the-box though.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre, it's save my time